# How compact-u16 construct works and is created?

Tags: transactions, message

I just started reading through solana documentation and stumbled upon compact-u16 struct.
To my understanding the sole reason for it existing is transferring less data via transaction by average, because by expectations it is more likely to receive array length
value that is less than 127 that way it stores it in a single byte array.
But the encoding part is confusing to me.

Let's say our value is: **132** **(0b10000100)**.

"The first byte contains the lower 7 bits of the value in its lower 7 bits.
If the value is above 0x7f, the high bit is set"

1. So first byte and its bits of our compact u16 array will contain: **10000100** [u8].

"Next 7 bits of the value are placed into the lower 7 bits of a second byte"

2. Now what? What are the next 7 bits of our value?

If possible would appreciate a full process of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each byte in a compact-u16 consists of 7 significant bits, and 1 continuation bit. Allow me to explain by denoting significant bits in **bold**, continuation bits in *italics*, and unused bits in plain text.

Consider this 16-bit number:

```
0000000000101100
zzyyyyyyyxxxxxxx
```

To construct a compact-u16 start by copying the 7 significant bits into the last 7 bits of the first byte. If, after this, non-zero bits remain to be encoded, we will need another byte; set the current byte's first bit to *1* to indicate that there's another byte to follow then repeat the steps above. Otherwise set it to *0* and stop.

```
  ┌ no more bytes required; stop.
[ 00101100 ]
   ^^^^^^^
   xxxxxxx
```

Consider another:

```
0110000100000001
zzyyyyyyyxxxxxxx
```

To represent this number in compact-u16, you'll need multiple bytes, and need to set continuation bits to indicate that multiple bytes are in play.

```
  ┌ continue ┌ continue
[ 10000001   11000010   00000001 ]
   ^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^         ^^
   xxxxxxx    yyyyyyy         zz
```

Note that in the first example you were able to store a 16-bit number in half the space, and in the second example you needed 1.5x as much space as normal. Compact-u16 only saves space if you expect to need fewer than two bytes, on average, for your typical workload.

Comment: this is a little confusing as the [bit-endianness is backwards](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/74f487c8281bb9e6322875359c95af97fec8d78c/sdk/program/src/short_vec.rs#L133-L136) (continuation is the MSB, not LSB). also omits that a value must be represented as its [shortest form](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/74f487c8281bb9e6322875359c95af97fec8d78c/sdk/program/src/short_vec.rs#L90-L92), not a longer alias (eg. legal zero: `0000_0000`, illegal zero: `1000_0000 0000_0000`)

Comment: Oops. Updating.

Comment: Thanks you explained it perfectly. So if I got this right value `10000100` would be stored in 2 bytes instead of 1 like this - `00000000 10000100` ?

Comment: Well, `10000100` is 8-bits worth of data, so presuming you mean the 16-bit number `0000000010000100` then yes-ish: in compact-u16 notation it would be `[10000100 00000001]`